# Usage of updateStateByKey() in Spark Streaming to produce a stream of state changes from a stream of raw events

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I've just started looking around for a solution for stateful computation with Spark Streaming when I came across the updateStateByKey() function.

The problem I'm trying to solve:
10,000 sensors produce a binary value every minute.

If consecutive values a sensor reports are different from each other, I would like to flag that and send it down Kafka as a state change event.

My assumption is that updateStateByKey() can be used in this example, however I'm not entirely aware of the recommended approach of implementing the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you will get a stream of (String, Int) pairs from the sensors where the String is the ID of the sensor and the Int is the binary value returned by the sensor.  With that assumption you could try something like this:

```
val sensorData: DStream[(String, Int)] = ???

val state = sensorData.updateStateByKey[(String, Int)](updateFunction _)

def updateFunction(newValues: Seq[(String, Int)], currentValues: Seq[(String, Int)]) = {
    val newValuesMap = newValues.toMap
    val currentValuesMap = currentValues.toMap

    currentValuesMap.keys.foreach ( (id) =>
            if(currrentValuesMap.get(id) != newValuesMap.getOrElse(id, -1)) {
                //send to Kafka
            }
    )       
    Some(newValues)
}
```

Comment: You are right about the (String, Int) pair, I'll try out your code and see how it works out. Thank you

Comment: Hi Patrick, can you do the same process with `.mapWithState()`?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any way the state's life/resource can be managed? Or it is always growing?

For example in [this sessionization example](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/11/how-to-do-near-real-time-sessionization-with-spark-streaming-and-apache-hadoop/), the state will grow forever right? Is there any way to manage that so you can purge/archive 3 month only aggregation data or something?

Comment: You can return whatever you want as the new state, so it is free for you to manage.  In the example in my answer above only the current state is stored each time, so it is not growing.  Probably best if you ask this as a fresh question though, rather than as an answer to the original posters question.